# Unable to train in Google Cloud ML

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm not being able to train in ML Engine. The training always stop around iteration 60. I have used Keras to build the model layers, but I train using `tf.Session`.

I get this error, but no traceback.

```
ERROR   2018-10-15 10:31:02 -0700   master-replica-0        name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB major: 6 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.3285
ERROR   2018-10-15 10:31:02 -0700   master-replica-0        pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0
ERROR   2018-10-15 10:31:02 -0700   master-replica-0        totalMemory: 15.90GiB freeMemory: 15.61GiB
```

My config.yaml. I tried different configurations. Same result.

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_p100
```

Job submission.

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME --labels="$LABELS" --verbosity='debug' --stream-logs --package-path=./job --module-name=job.task --staging-bucket="$TRAIN_BUCKET" --region=us-central1 --runtime-version 1.10 --config=job/config.yaml
```

Full logs

```
INFO    2018-10-15 10:28:37 -0700   service     Validating job requirements...
INFO    2018-10-15 10:28:38 -0700   service     Job creation request has been successfully validated.
INFO    2018-10-15 10:28:38 -0700   service     Job <JOB_NAME> is queued.
INFO    2018-10-15 10:28:38 -0700   service     Waiting for job to be provisioned.
INFO    2018-10-15 10:28:41 -0700   service     Waiting for training program to start.
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:03 -0700   master-replica-0        Running task with arguments: --cluster={"master": ["127.0.0.1:2222"]} --task={"type": "master", "index": 0} --job={  "scale_tier": "CUSTOM",  "master_type": "standard_p100",  "package_uris": ["gs://annotator-1286-ml/<JOB_NAME>/5b038627d10c914d6309269cefff8d2e0682f87f441bdb8c547a05e8ed1107a7/job-0.0.0.tar.gz"],  "python_module": "job.task",  "region": "us-central1",  "runtime_version": "1.10",  "run_on_raw_vm": true}
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:15 -0700   master-replica-0        Running module job.task.
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:15 -0700   master-replica-0        Downloading the package: gs://annotator-1286-ml/<JOB_NAME>/5b038627d10c914d6309269cefff8d2e0682f87f441bdb8c547a05e8ed1107a7/job-0.0.0.tar.gz
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:15 -0700   master-replica-0        Running command: gsutil -q cp gs://annotator-1286-ml/<JOB_NAME>/5b038627d10c914d6309269cefff8d2e0682f87f441bdb8c547a05e8ed1107a7/job-0.0.0.tar.gz job-0.0.0.tar.gz
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:22 -0700   master-replica-0        Installing the package: gs://annotator-1286-ml/<JOB_NAME>/5b038627d10c914d6309269cefff8d2e0682f87f441bdb8c547a05e8ed1107a7/job-0.0.0.tar.gz
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:22 -0700   master-replica-0        Running command: pip install --user --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-deps job-0.0.0.tar.gz
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:28 -0700   master-replica-0        Processing ./job-0.0.0.tar.gz
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:29 -0700   master-replica-0        Building wheels for collected packages: job
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:29 -0700   master-replica-0          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for job: started
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:29 -0700   master-replica-0          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for job: finished with status 'done'
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:29 -0700   master-replica-0          Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b8/10/df/bb59eda2baac79b36fbdb8e5305ada7d6bf7779be49c3c5a0d
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:29 -0700   master-replica-0        Successfully built job
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:29 -0700   master-replica-0        Installing collected packages: job
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:29 -0700   master-replica-0        Successfully installed job-0.0.0
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:30 -0700   master-replica-0        Running command: pip install --user job-0.0.0.tar.gz
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:30 -0700   master-replica-0        Processing ./job-0.0.0.tar.gz
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:30 -0700   master-replica-0        Building wheels for collected packages: job
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:30 -0700   master-replica-0          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for job: started
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:30 -0700   master-replica-0          Running setup.py bdist_wheel for job: finished with status 'done'
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:30 -0700   master-replica-0          Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b8/10/df/bb59eda2baac79b36fbdb8e5305ada7d6bf7779be49c3c5a0d
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:30 -0700   master-replica-0        Successfully built job
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:31 -0700   master-replica-0        Installing collected packages: job
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:31 -0700   master-replica-0          Found existing installation: job 0.0.0
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:31 -0700   master-replica-0            Uninstalling job-0.0.0:
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:31 -0700   master-replica-0              Successfully uninstalled job-0.0.0
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:31 -0700   master-replica-0        Successfully installed job-0.0.0
INFO    2018-10-15 10:30:31 -0700   master-replica-0        Running command: python -m job.task
INFO    2018-10-15 10:31:02 -0700   master-replica-0        successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
INFO    2018-10-15 10:31:02 -0700   master-replica-0        Found device 0 with properties: 
ERROR   2018-10-15 10:31:02 -0700   master-replica-0        name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB major: 6 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.3285
ERROR   2018-10-15 10:31:02 -0700   master-replica-0        pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0
ERROR   2018-10-15 10:31:02 -0700   master-replica-0        totalMemory: 15.90GiB freeMemory: 15.61GiB
INFO    2018-10-15 10:31:02 -0700   master-replica-0        Adding visible gpu devices: 0
INFO    2018-10-15 10:31:03 -0700   master-replica-0        Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
INFO    2018-10-15 10:31:03 -0700   master-replica-0             0 
INFO    2018-10-15 10:31:03 -0700   master-replica-0        0:   N 
INFO    2018-10-15 10:31:03 -0700   master-replica-0        Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 15127 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 6.0)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        Mon Oct 15 17:32:06 2018       
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        | NVIDIA-SMI 396.26                 Driver Version: 396.26                    |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        |===============================+======================+======================|
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        |   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        | N/A   46C    P0   172W / 250W |  15619MiB / 16280MiB |     82%      Default |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0                                                                                       
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        | Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        |  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        |=============================================================================|
INFO    2018-10-15 10:32:06 -0700   master-replica-0        +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        Mon Oct 15 17:37:06 2018       
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        | NVIDIA-SMI 396.26                 Driver Version: 396.26                    |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        |===============================+======================+======================|
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        |   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        | N/A   52C    P0    39W / 250W |  15619MiB / 16280MiB |     33%      Default |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0                                                                                       
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        | Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        |  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        |=============================================================================|
INFO    2018-10-15 10:37:06 -0700   master-replica-0        +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Setting Parameters
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        get_personlab: Create data source
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        get_personlab: Parse tfrecords
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        get_personlab: Apply transformations
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        get_personlab: Parametrize Dataset
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Build Model
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        get_personlab: Define input sizes to Keras tensors and assign image tensor
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        get_personlab: Resnet
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("pool1/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 99, 99, 64), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res2a_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 99, 99, 256), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res2b_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 99, 99, 256), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res2c_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 99, 99, 256), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res3a_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 50, 50, 512), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res3b1_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 50, 50, 512), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res3b2_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 50, 50, 512), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4a_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b1_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b2_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b3_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b4_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b5_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b6_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b7_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b8_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b9_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b10_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b11_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b12_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b13_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b14_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b15_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b16_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b17_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b18_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b19_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b20_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b21_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res4b22_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 1024), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res5a_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 2048), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res5b_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 2048), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("res5c_relu/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 2048), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        get_personlab: PersonLab Head
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        build_personlab_head: Add kp_maps
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("kp_maps/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 2048), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        build_personlab_head: Add short_offsets
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("short_offsets/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 2048), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        build_personlab_head: Add mid_offsets
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("mid_offsets/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 25, 25, 2048), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("kp_maps_tConv1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 50, 50, 1048), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("kp_maps_tConv2/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 100, 100, 512), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("kp_maps_tConv3/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 200, 200, 256), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("kp_maps_tConv3_1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 400, 400, 17), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("short_offsets_tConv1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 50, 50, 1048), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("short_offsets_tConv2/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 100, 100, 512), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("short_offsets_tConv3/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 200, 200, 256), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("short_offsets_tConv3_1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 400, 400, 34), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("mid_offsets_tConv1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 50, 50, 1048), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("mid_offsets_tConv2/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 100, 100, 512), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("mid_offsets_tConv3/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 200, 200, 256), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Tensor("mid_offsets_tConv3_1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 400, 400, 64), dtype=float32)
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Add loss and training operations
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Create Saver object
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Initialize variables
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        Training
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        ('iteration: ', '0')
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        ('iteration: ', '10')
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        ('iteration: ', '20')
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        ('iteration: ', '30')
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        ('iteration: ', '40')
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        ('iteration: ', '50')
INFO    2018-10-15 10:38:36 -0700   master-replica-0        ('iteration: ', '60')
```

[image: CPU and Memory]

How can I get more detailed information about the error?

Update: I'm fetching data from Google Cloud Storage. I followed `https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance`.

Comment: The ERROR log is actually not error but mis-classified as one. I don't think the issue is related to that.
Quick question, are you able to run the same code locally?

It would be helpful if you can send the job id to cloudml-feedback@google.com

Comment: Yes, I run locally. I just sent, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figure out it was very very slow. So it gave me the impression the problem was on the training. I presumed was a problem with distributed training because Keras layers.

I changed the config to use `complex_model_l_gpu` and it worked.